# RHIPE Installation error After Installing Hadoop , R for Single Node Cluster?

Tags: hadoop

i am trying to install RHIP by using this link,

http://ksssblogs.blogspot.com/2011/09/working-of-r-on-hadooprhipe.html

i have configured all things successfully while executing "R CMD INSTALL Rhipe_0.69.tar.gz"

i am getting this error,

```
[root@localhost ~]# R CMD INSTALL Rhipe_0.69.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘Rhipe’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
g++ -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/usr/local/lib/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c rexp.pb.cc -o rexp.pb.o
In file included from rexp.pb.cc:4:
rexp.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
rexp.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
rexp.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘void REXP::clear_rawvalue()’:
rexp.pb.h:672: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘void REXP::set_rawvalue(const std::string&)’:
rexp.pb.h:682: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘void REXP::set_rawvalue(const char*)’:
rexp.pb.h:689: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘void REXP::set_rawvalue(const void*, size_t)’:
rexp.pb.h:696: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘std::string* REXP::mutable_rawvalue()’:
rexp.pb.h:703: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘std::string* REXP::release_rawvalue()’:
rexp.pb.h:710: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h:714: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘void STRING::clear_strval()’:
rexp.pb.h:853: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘void STRING::set_strval(const std::string&)’:
rexp.pb.h:863: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘void STRING::set_strval(const char*)’:
rexp.pb.h:870: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘void STRING::set_strval(const char*, size_t)’:
rexp.pb.h:877: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘std::string* STRING::mutable_strval()’:
rexp.pb.h:884: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h: In member function ‘std::string* STRING::release_strval()’:
rexp.pb.h:891: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.h:895: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.cc: In member function ‘void REXP::SharedCtor()’:
rexp.pb.cc:256: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.cc: In member function ‘void REXP::SharedDtor()’:
rexp.pb.cc:265: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.cc: In member function ‘virtual void REXP::Clear()’:
rexp.pb.cc:296: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.cc: In member function ‘void STRING::SharedCtor()’:
rexp.pb.cc:905: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.cc: In member function ‘void STRING::SharedDtor()’:
rexp.pb.cc:915: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
rexp.pb.cc: In member function ‘virtual void STRING::Clear()’:
rexp.pb.cc:945: error: ‘kEmptyString’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
make: *** [rexp.pb.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rhipe’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rhipe’
* restoring previous ‘/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rhipe’
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have occurs due to the absence of bin-utils. Is this Ubuntu you are installing on? If so  you would need to install binutils-gold package.

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
```